# How to use Item Pipeline while using Item Loader in parse?

Tags: python, scrapy

The Item Pipe line function does not work when `parse` returns a item through Item Loader's load_item method

```
def parse(self,response):
    DIV_SELECTOR = '.Content'
    SET_SELECTOR = '.Meta'

    for div in response.css(DIV_SELECTOR):            
        rowSelector = div.css(SET_SELECTOR)
        ItemAAA= ItemLoader(item=ItemAAA(), selector=rowSelector)
        ItemAAA.add_css('name','a ::text')
        ItemAAA.add_css('url','a ::attr(href)')
        return ItemAAA.load_item()
```

The pipeline method is recognised by scrapy:

```
2017-01-10 18:25:48     [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:  ['pipeline.DuplicatesPipeline']
```

The pipeline works when the `parse` function returns a dict:

```
def parse(self,response):
    for  tt in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
            NAME_SELECTOR = 'a ::text'
            yield { 'name': tt.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                   }
```

**Pipeline.py**

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class DuplicatesPipeline(object):

   def __init__(self):
       self.ids_seen = set()

   def process_item(self, item, spider):
       if item['name'] in self.ids_seen:
          raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
       else:
          self.ids_seen.add(item['name'])
          return item
```

I am using Python 3.5.2, scrapy 1.3 through Anaconda in Windows 7

Comment: Are you sure `ItemAAA.load_item()` returns an item? It could be that it returns an empty item. Try logging/printing it before return and see if something ends up in your log. Also in a loop you should `yield` instead of `return` since return will break the loop and you'll only get one item.

Comment: `load_item` method returns the item according to the documentation: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.loader.ItemLoader.load_item

Comment: Yes it does return `scrapy.Item` but if no xpaths found anything or loader proccesing ended up with empty strings then you essentially end up with an empty Items.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are returning only 1 item in your parse() method since you are breaking the loop with `return` statement. To remedy this simply use `yield` instead of return to turn your method into a generator:

```
def parse(self,response):
    DIV_SELECTOR = '.Content'
    SET_SELECTOR = '.Meta'

    for div in response.css(DIV_SELECTOR):            
        rowSelector = div.css(SET_SELECTOR)
        ItemAAA= ItemLoader(item=ItemAAA(), selector=rowSelector)
        ItemAAA.add_css('name','a ::text')
        ItemAAA.add_css('url','a ::attr(href)')
        return ItemAAA.load_item()  <--- incorrect
        yield ItemAAA.load_item()  <--- correct
```

Comment: Hi Granitosaurus, Thanks for the suggestion. The `yield` statement also did not work. The temporary fix is to `yield` the `Item` directly. rather than using 'ItemLoader'

Comment: I tried before, not working for too, seems Item is the only currently.